# My observable value is not displayed despite the ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I apologize first of all for my English which is not good at all. I am asking for your help today, because I am having an incomprehensible problem!

I'm currently on Angular and using .subscribe to track my obsersables.
Here is my component:

```
export class SiteDetailComponent implements OnInit {

public test1 : ISite = <ISite>{};
public test2: ISite[] = [];

public errMsg : string = "";
constructor(...)


ngOnInit() {
const id : number = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));

this.SiteListeService.getSiteById(id).subscribe({
  next: site => {
    this.test1 = site;
  },
  error: err => this.errMsg = err
});

this.SiteListeService.getSites().subscribe({
  next: sites => {
    this.test2 = sites;

  },
  error: err => this.errMsg = err
});
```

As you can see I made a .subscribe on 2 Observable: this;SiteListeService.getSites() and this.SiteListeService.getSiteById(id), here is the service concerned (which I have imported the constructor).

```
public getSites(): Observable<ISite[]> {
return this.http.get<ISite[]>(this.HOTEL_API_URL + "test/").pipe(
  tap(test2 => console.log('test2 : ', test2)),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
}

public getSiteById(id : number): Observable<ISite> {
  return this.http.get<ISite>(this.HOTEL_API_URL + "test/" + id).pipe(
    tap(test1 => console.log('test1 : ', test1)),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

The problem being that the test1 variable that I use in my .html does not want to be displayed, here is the example:

```
<h5 class="card-title">{{ test1.nom }} </h5>
```

On the other hand my test2 variable that I use in the same .html works, example:

```
<div class="col mb-4" *ngFor="let t2 of test2">
<h5 class="card-title">{{ t2.nom }}</h5>
```

What I don't understand is why one displays and the other does not! I however put both in the ngOnInit() so that it is treated in priority!

in my service I made a console.log of what my https requests return to me, and everything is working correctly...
This is what the google chrome console shows me :

[image]

I hope I have provided you with all the necessary information, sorry if my words are not correct I am not a professional. Thank you in advance for reading!

Comment: What's going on is very clear from the console message. In both cases, the server is responding with an array of data. When you request a single item, it is still returning an array which contains that item. That's something you should fix on the back-end if possible but if not, you need to unwrap it in your service. Also, looks like you have away too much error handling code. You're going to miss errors. Get that crap out of there.

Comment: So the problem is that I return an array in json in my backend?

So I have to use a *ngFor="let t1 of test1"> and change the variable type from t1 to ISite[] ?

What do you mean for error codes?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that. I would suggest that you unwrap it in your service so that you can handle it like a single item in your view. If you are writing the backend yourself fix the backend so it returns the kind of response you expect. Regarding Arrowhead Lake, you don't want to catch errors, especially early in development, because you want them to propagate and cause failure down the line.

Comment: I changed my backend which now sends me a single object and not an array! Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the service method `getSiteById` was on line 30 when you got the log entries from your message, the http request is returning an array:

[image]

Your functions are expecting an object instead. So when you assign your variable test1 here:

```
   this.test1 = site;
```

it becomes an array with a single element.

There are a few option to resolve this:

1. change it to get the first element

```
   this.test1 = site[0];
```

2. this could also be done at the service function

```
public getSiteById(id : number): Observable<ISite> {
  return this.http.get<ISite[]>(this.HOTEL_API_URL + "test/" + id).pipe(
    map(data => data[0]),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

3. change your BackEnd for this request so it return the element and not an array.

Comment: Exactly. I think you are listing the options in reverse order of desirability but that's my opinion.

Comment: Not sure if it is wise to bind the OP to preferences. Let us leave it as is

Comment: Well, if he doesn't fix the server then he needs to add code that would stimulate a 404 on the client if he wants is good to follow any kind of standard pattern. but sure. I voted for this anyway I just think it could be better

Comment: I changed my backend which now sends me a single object and not an array! Thank you so much !!